# order data by timestamp in descending order from firestore

Tags: android, flutter, dart

im failing to order my data by timestamp in descending order, error keeps saying  have positioned it wrong

```
                StreamBuilder( 
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("payments").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").where('participants', arrayContains: userActive).snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){


                    
                 

                  return Container ( child:ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    controller: ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){

                      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index].data();
```

Comment: And what is making you fail? Share your attempt.

Comment: this is my attempt StreamBuilder( 
                      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("payments").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").where('participants', arrayContains: userActive).snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot){

Comment: but it keeps saying i have positioned it wrong

Comment: Please edit you attempt into the question and give a *specific* error.

Comment: Edit in the error. Be specific about what's wrong with this attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following:

```dart
orderBy("timestamp", descending : true)
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/f5a408f0aed529da5602d4562964d60ff50d2a7e/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L224